# "Run as program" does not open a terminal window

Tags: command-line, scripts, nautilus

I am use Ubuntu 22.04 (on Ukrainian language). I want to run my scripts (like .py) quickly, but:

- if I use function "Run as a program" in File Manager (Nautilus) it work is correct (a terminal window opens)
- but if I use this function from desktop nothing opens (although the script, according to my observations, is executed).

How can this be fixed?

[video](https://youtu.be/xf7TCfduIm4)

Answer (score 2):

When run from the desktop, the script is not started in a newly launched terminal, but runs in the background without being connected to standard output. That must be a limitation of the gnome shell extension that implements the desktop icons. You will need to launch these scripts from the file manager until that is fixed.